# Update only part of the page when new SMS arrives in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an .aspx page. User will send an SMS in the application. For each new SMS for particular user, an alert button will be updated with image as unread message. Now I want to update only selected part whenever any new message arrives in the database. I don't want to schedule partial page refresh at regular time interval. Page has to be refreshed if and only if new message arrives. 
How can I achieve this task? How to get intimation from the database(SQL Server 2008) at the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no means for the SQL server to intimate the front end since the DB server will not have any client knowledge.

Only way I can think is some kind of ajax poll that will check the db and update the image when the message is received